# Как редиректить с http на https в mamp pro?

Tags: php, apache, laravel

Разрабатываю сайт пока на локальном сервере mamp pro, сам сайт на laravel 5.
Настроил чтобы хост работал по https, но по http теперь отдается белая страница, как сделать редирект с http на https?

В оригинале .htaccess выглядит так:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

   </IfModule>
```

Пробовал добавлять:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Не сработало

**UPD1:** похоже дело в mamp pro, я попробовал сделал ошибку в .htaccess , по https выдает 500 ошибку, а по http белую страницу, запрос кажется не доходит до .htaccess

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` в открытую сообщает о том, что это последнее правило, после его срабатывания обработка не ведется. Если после него что-то добавлять, то оно и не будет работать.

Comment: Я до этого правила вставлял, похоже дело в mamp pro, я попробовал сделал ошибку в .htaccess , по https выдает 500 ошибку, а по http белую страницу, запрос кажется не доходит до .htaccess

Comment: Посмотрите логи apache. Там должна быть подробная информация о причинах ошибки.  

Почти уверен, что проблема вот в этих строках:  

    `<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>`

Попробуйте их закомментировать и проверить снова.

Comment: Попробовал, убрал - не помогло. Лог апача нашел, ничего не пишет в лог когда запрашиваю адрес по http

Comment: А nginx настроен? В его логах тоже пусто?

Comment: mamp pro на apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# Перевод на HTTPS:
# без www если www есть он добавить автоматом.
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Тепер если нет www добавляем его к https.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


 # Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Тоже была такая пробюлема ошибка была #Handle Front Controller Нужно было перенести эту строку `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`
Надеюсь поможет и вам.